# Select multiple files shown on JTable and download them from the MySQL database

Tags: java, mysql, swing, jtable

I have written code for `JButton` to download selected files represented on a `JTable` from the MySQL database. I want it to download all selected files.Initially i was able to download one file at a time.now i have edited the code and it does nothing and returns no error. what could be wrong in the code.

How can I achieve this in my code?

My code:

```
private void jButtonDownloadActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {

    int BUFFER_SIZE = 4096;

    try {
         int[] selected_rows= jTable1.getSelectedRows();
         for (int i = 0; i < selected_rows.length;  i++){
             if (i < selected_rows.length - 1 ) {
        String tableClick=(jTable1.getModel().getValueAt(selected_rows[i],i).toString());
    Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/employee_certificate","root","");
        String sql= "SELECT Cert, Cert_Name FROM certificate WHERE Cert_Code =?" ;
        PreparedStatement pstmt =  con.prepareStatement(sql);
        pstmt.setString(1, tableClick);
        ResultSet rs=pstmt.executeQuery();
        if(rs.next()){
            String filename = rs.getString("Cert_Name");
            Blob blob = rs.getBlob("Cert");
            InputStream inputStream = blob.getBinaryStream();
            String filePath ="C:\\Users\\User\\Downloads\\Documents\\"+filename;
            OutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream(filePath);

            int bytesRead = -1;
            byte[] buffer = new byte[BUFFER_SIZE];
            while ((bytesRead = inputStream.read(buffer)) != -1) {
                outputStream.write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
            }

            inputStream.close();
            outputStream.close();
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"file saved to Documents in your C folder.");
        }}} }
        catch (Exception e)
        {JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,e);}}
```

Comment: Use [`JTable.getSelectedRows()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/JTable.html#getSelectedRows--) instead of `getSelectedRow()` for an `int[]`. Loop the integer array and perform the code seen in the method. Two notes though: 1) Much more user freindly (& robust) to pop a `JFileChooser` to allow the *user* to select a directory to download files to. (Put that before the loop.) 2) Make sure the showing of the option pane is taken outside the loop, and that it also informs the user of the number of files downloaded.

Comment: Don't post code in comments where it is illegible. Instead edit the question using the small `edit` link below the tags. For better help sooner, post a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/).

Comment: That is no MCVE, just uncompilable code snippets. If you should *ever* get around to posting an MCVE, ensure it uses a logical and consistent form of indenting code lines and blocks.  The indentation is intended to make the flow of the code easier to follow!

Comment: I am sorry I don't understand. Do you have an example of MCVE? Or what yu are asking for?

Comment: Follow & read both links in my 2nd comment. It is explained quite well what ***you*** need to do (& why, in the 2nd link).

Comment: I think if someone has sample code of what i want could help understand how to do this because building MCVE could take me some time now.

Comment: *"..if someone has sample code.."* I'm sure someone does, but SO is not the place to come looking for it. It's not a help desk. Not a code generation machine. *"..building MCVE could take me some time now."* So get started. What you're saying comes across as though your time is more valuable than that of other people who help here for free.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finaly i got it. Many thanks to @Thompson. i need to use JTable.getSelectedRows() instead of JTable.getSelectedRow() then loop the array as shown:

```
       int[] selected_rows= jTable1.getSelectedRows();
         Object[] row= new Object[6];
         for (int i = 0; i < selected_rows.length;  i++){
             for (int r = 0; r < row.length;  r++){
        String tableClick=   (jTable1.getModel().getValueAt(selected_rows[i],r).toString());
```